# Pass values to another window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
var createAccountViewModel = new CreateAccountViewModel();
var createAccountView = new CreateAccount(createAccountViewModel)
{
    CheckAccount = {Visibility =  Visibility.Hidden},
    UpdateButton = {Visibility = Visibility.Visible },
    AddEmployeButton = {Visibility =  Visibility.Hidden},
    NomEmp = {Text = SelectedEmp.NomEmp},
    PrenomEmp = {Text =SelectedEmp.PrenomEmp },
    DateRecrutement = { SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedEmp.DateRecrut) },
    DateNaissance = {SelectedDate =  Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedEmp.DnEmp)}
};
```

I have a `DataGrid` and a button in each line that runs the code above. I want to get the cells content of each row and pass them to a new window.

The visibility is being changed however, the content (text and selected date) are not. The window is basically empty like If I didn't send anything and I have no errors. (`SelectedEmp` is working fine by the way so It's not from there either).

My window is mainly for adding employees to my database  so I want to use the same interface for editing employees as the GUI has the same fields I'll need.

My guess (I could be wrong) that this is not working because the `Text/SelectedDate` are bound to properties in the view model? What is more recommended to do in this case?

Create the same GUI again or instead of passing values to the window, I should pass them through the view model constructor?

Comment: Are both Windows from your same project? Can you share a ViewModel to allow access to the same values? How do you launch the second window?

Comment: If `CreateAccount` is a `Form` then call `createAccountView.Show()`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought It's obvious. Yes, I use createAccountView.Show(); to open. and yes, they are both in the same project.

Comment: You could pass same ViewModel to second window bind some of fields to this VM

Answer (score 0):

Passing the values to the ViewModel properties did the trick:

```
            var createAccountViewModel = new CreateAccountViewModel
        {
            NomEmp = SelectedEmp.NomEmp
            ,PrenomEmp = SelectedEmp.PrenomEmp,
            DateRecrutement = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedEmp.DateRecrut),
            DateNaissance = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedEmp.DnEmp),
            NumTel =  SelectedEmp.TelEmp


        };
        var createAccountView = new CreateAccount(createAccountViewModel)
        {
            CheckAccount = {Visibility = Visibility.Hidden},
            UpdateButton = {Visibility = Visibility.Visible},
            AddEmployeButton = {Visibility = Visibility.Hidden},
        };
```